# Codeigniter files upload e.g docx etc Blank Pages after download

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

Hellog Guys Any one Could help me On upload files I have a issue On upload files because After Uploading file ..The file Uploaded by teacher Like Docx, doc or etch will be Blank after download it

Here is my Code

```
    $subjectCode    =   $this->input->post('CheckId');
    $filename   =   $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($subjectCode) ; $i++) {
        $seatworkData = array(
            'teacher_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'subject_id' => $subjectCode[$i],
            'student_id' => "0",
            'seatwork_title' => 'seatwork '.trim($this->input->post('input_seatwork_title')),
            'editor_content' => trim($this->input->post('textarea_seatwork')),
            'attached_file' =>   $filename,
            'type' => 'seatwork',
            'term' => trim($this->input->post('select_term')),
            'score' => trim($this->input->post('input_activity_score')),
            'status' => 1,
            'deadline' => trim($this->input->post('input_deadline')),
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
        );

        $term = str_replace(' ','',$seatworkData['term']);
        if (!file_exists('./public/uploads/activities/seatworks/'.$term.'/')) {
                mkdir('./public/uploads/activities/seatworks/'.$term.'/', 0777, true);
        }
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = './public/uploads/activities/seatworks/'.$term;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|docx|xlsx|pptx';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        $config['detect_mime'] = TRUE;
        $config['mod_mime_fix'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['file_ext_tolower'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $files = $_FILES;
        if ($files) {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $files['userfile']['name'];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $files['userfile']['type'];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $files['userfile']['tmp_name'];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $files['userfile']['error'];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $files['userfile']['size'];
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $data['response'] = "false";
                $data['errors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            } else {
                $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                $images[] = $fileName;
                $udata['upload_data'] = array($this->upload->data());
                $data_type = $udata['upload_data'];
                foreach ($data_type as $val)
                {
                        $file_ext = $val['file_ext'];
                        $orig_file = $val['orig_name'];
                }
                $new_name = $term.'_'.time().'_'.rand(0,100000)."".$file_ext;
                rename($config['upload_path'].'/'.$orig_file, $config['upload_path'].'/'.$new_name);
                $seatworkData['attached_file'] = trim($new_name);
            }
        }

        $this->activities->create_seatwork($seatworkData);
```

here is example of image
After UPLOAD FILE
[image]

After download file this is the output of file that i upload

[image]

Download function on controller:

```
public function download_file() { 
   $name =$this->uri->segment(5); 
   $term = $this->uri->segment(4); 
   $type = $this->uri->segment(3); 
   $this->load->helper('file'); 
   $this->load->helper('download'); 
   $pth = file_get_contents(base_url()."public/uploads/activities/".$type."/".$term. "/".$name); 
   $nme = $name; force_download($nme, $pth); 
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the code to perform the download?

Comment: OK sure                      public function download_file()
      {
         $name =$this->uri->segment(5);
          $term = $this->uri->segment(4);
          $type = $this->uri->segment(3);

          $this->load->helper('file');
          $this->load->helper('download');
          $pth    =   file_get_contents(base_url()."public/uploads/activities/".$type."/".$term. "/".$name);
          $nme    =   $name;
          force_download($nme, $pth);


      }

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the upload function but in the download function.

Your download function should be something like this because you're not generating a new file to download, you want to download an existing file.

If you want to download an existing file from your server you’ll need to do the following:

```
public function download_file() { 
   $name = $this->uri->segment(5); 
   $term = $this->uri->segment(4); 
   $type = $this->uri->segment(3); 
   $this->load->helper('download'); 
   $nme = $name; 
   force_download(
      base_url("public/uploads/activities/".$type."/".$term. "/".$name), 
      NULL
   ); 
}
```

Like the docs say here: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html?highlight=download

Contents of photo.jpg will be automatically read

```
force_download('/path/to/photo.jpg', NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you But ill try later